# mysql one-to-many query with negation and/or multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, one-to-many

I thought a query like this would be pretty easy because of the nature of relational databases but it seems to be giving me a fit.  I also searched around but found nothing that really helped.  Here's the situation:

Let's say I have a simple relationship for products and product tags.  This is a one-to-many relationship, so we could have the following:

```
productid  |  tag
========================
1          |  Car
1          |  Black
1          |  Ford
2          |  Car
2          |  Red
2          |  Ford
3          |  Car
3          |  Black
3          |  Lexus
4          |  Motorcycle
4          |  Black
5          |  Skateboard
5          |  Black
6          |  Skateboard
6          |  Green
```

What's the **most efficient** way to query for all `(Ford OR Black OR Skateboard) AND NOT (Motorcycles OR Green)`?  Another query I'm going to need to do is something like all `(Car) or (Skateboard) or (Green AND Motorcycle) or (Red AND Motorcycle)`.

There are about 150k records in the products table and 600k records in the tags tables, so the query is going to need to be as efficient as possible. Here's one query that I've been messing around with (example #1), but it seems to be taking about 4 seconds or so. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT p.productid
FROM   products p
       JOIN producttags tag1 USING (productid)
WHERE  p.active = 1
       AND tag1.tag IN ( 'Ford', 'Black', 'Skatebaord' )
       AND p.productid NOT IN (SELECT productid
                               FROM   producttags
                               WHERE  tag IN ( 'Motorcycle', 'Green' ));
```

## Update

The quickest query I've found so far is something like this.  It's taking 100-200ms but it seems pretty inflexible and ugly.  Basically I'm grabbing all products that match `Ford`, `Black`, or `Skateboard`.  Them I'm concatenating all of the tags for those matched products into a colon-separated string and removing all products that match on `:Green:` AND `:Motorcycle:`.  Any thoughts?

```
SELECT p.productid,
       Concat(':', Group_concat(alltags.tag SEPARATOR ':'), ':') AS taglist
FROM   products p
       JOIN producttags tag1 USING (productid)
       JOIN producttags alltags USING (productid)
WHERE  p.active = 1
       AND tag1.tag IN ( 'Ford', 'Black', 'Skateboard' )
GROUP  BY tag1.productid
HAVING ( taglist NOT LIKE '%:Motorcycle:%'
         AND taglist NOT LIKE '%:Green:%' );
```

Comment: Are you able to execute the subquery for the productids for Motorcycle and Green in advance? If so, passing those into the in clause (or using not equals) will probably give you a better result.

Comment: Because of the structure I'm given it would be pretty difficult to accomplish, but it's definitely something I'll be toying around with.

Comment: What indexes exist on the products and the tag tables?  Also, what is the typical amount of products assigned to each tag?  Are we talking 10, 100, 1000, 10000 products in each tag on average?

Comment: Primary on (productid, tag) and index on (tag).  Anywhere between 1-15 tags per product and a wide range of probably 1-30,000 products per tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write the exclusion join with no subqueries:

```
SELECT p.productid
FROM   products p
INNER JOIN producttags AS t ON p.productid = t.productid
LEFT OUTER JOIN producttags AS x ON p.productid = x.productid 
       AND x.tag IN ('Motorcycle', 'Green')
WHERE  p.active = 1
       AND t.tag IN ( 'Ford', 'Black', 'Skateboard' )
       AND x.productid IS NULL;
```

Make sure you have an index on products over the two columns (active, productid) in that order.

You should also have an index on producttags over the two columns (productid, tag) in that order.

*Another query I'm going to need to do is something like all (Car) or (Skateboard) or (Green AND Motorcycle) or (Red AND Motorcycle).*

Sometimes these complex conditions are hard for the MySQL optimizer.  One common workaround is to use UNION to combine simpler queries:

```
SELECT p.productid
FROM   products p
INNER JOIN producttags AS t1 ON p.productid = t1.productid
WHERE  p.active = 1
   AND t1.tag IN ('Car', 'Skateboard')

UNION ALL

SELECT p.productid
FROM   products p
INNER JOIN producttags AS t1 ON p.productid = t1.productid
INNER JOIN producttags AS t2 ON p.productid = t2.productid 
WHERE  p.active = 1
   AND t1.tag IN ('Motorcycle')
   AND t2.tag IN ('Green', 'Red');
```

PS: Your tagging table is not an Entity-Attribute-Value table.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This seems to be the quickest and most organized answer yet.  I also removed the EAV tag - thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

I would get all the unique ID matches and the unique IDs to filter out, then LEFT JOIN those lists (as per tigeryan) and filter out any IDs that match. The query should also be easier to read and modify by keeping all the queries separate. It should be fairly quick also, although it may not look like it.

```
SELECT * FROM products p
WHERE 
p.active=1 AND
productid IN (
SELECT matches.productid FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT productid FROM producttags 
  WHERE tag IN ('Ford','Green','Skatebaord')
) AS matches
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT productid FROM producttags 
  WHERE tag IN ('Motorcycles','Green')
) AS filter ON filter.productid=matches.productid
WHERE filter.productid IS NULL
)
```

Sometimes a JOIN is faster than an IN, depending on how mysql optimizes the query:

```
SELECT p.* FROM (
SELECT matches.productid FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT productid FROM producttags 
  WHERE tag IN ('Ford','Green','Skatebaord')
) AS matches
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT productid FROM producttags 
  WHERE tag IN ('Motorcycles','Green')
) AS filter ON filter.productid=matches.productid
WHERE filter.productid IS NULL
) AS idfilter
    JOIN products p ON p.productid=idfilter.productid AND p.active=1
```

The second query should force the join order since the internal selects have to be done first.

Comment: This query is relatively fast because it gets rid of the `NOT IN` predicate. This is relatively common pattern used with EAV-type schemas (actually applicable to all kinds of schemas, but EAV models tend to "encourage" these highly versatile queries).  Also well done on readability!

Comment: I quickly tried this out the other day and from what I could tell the query was still taking an excessively long time.  I'm going to mess around with it again later today and report back.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: This query is still taking roughly 3-4 seconds with the proper indexes on both tables.  Here's the explain from the query: http://i.imgur.com/ZWXeo.png

Comment: The problem is that it is only using the "active" index. You might want to have an index on productid+active since you are probably always filtering on those two.

Comment: I added a new index on (active,productid) and mysql still chose to only use the active index.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually attack this by trying to eliminate records in the from...

```
select p.productid 
from product p 
left join producttags tag1 
    on p.productid = tag1.productid and tag1.tag NOT IN ('Motorcycles','Green')
where tag1.tag IN ('Ford','Black','Skateboard') and p.active = 1
```

Comment: Hmm, I like the idea but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.  I need to grab all products with the Ford or Black or Skateboard tag, but they cannot also have Motorcycle or Green tag.  This means that a black motorcycle would not be returned in the result set, but I believe this is the case in your example.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id FROM products AS p
JOIN producttags AS included ON (
    included.productid = p.id
    AND included.tag IN ('Ford', 'Black', 'Skatebaord') 
)
WHERE active = 1
AND p.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT productid FROM producttags
    WHERE tag IN ('Motorcycle', 'Green')
)
```

Comment: DISTINCT coupled with WHERE? That will slow down your database and cripple your processor if you have got a decent sized database!!

Comment: @SPI Correct. How would you get rid of duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the CONCAT/LIKE solution:

```
SELECT p.productid
FROM products p
JOIN producttags USING (productid)
WHERE p.active = 1
AND tag IN ('Ford', 'Black', 'Skateboard')
GROUP BY p.productid
HAVING SUM(IF(tag IN ('Motorcycle','Green'), 1, 0)) = 0;
```